# What is going wrong with my serialzation/deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization

Been breaking my head over this homework assignment.  It was supposed to take 7 hours, and I've got 12 in it.  There are several classes involved here, but I will try for an overview. Assignment8 class has main method, with case switch for user options.  The main method constructs a Store object(from  store class) that contains an array list with customer objects (parsed from user inputs and created in Customer class) and computer objects(handled similarly to customers).

Here is the part I'm stuck on now.  There is an option to serialize the store object to a file specified by the user(I'm supposed to use "store.dat").  After, I'm supposed to clear the array lists of customers and objects, then DE-serialize the file to an object, verify it's a Store object, and cast the object back into a store.  None of my exceptions are thrown, and everything seems to go swimmingly until I try to list my customers (which works before serializing).  It returns "no customers" indicating the array list has size 0.  I've not tried inputting computers yet, just customers.

I'm posting the parts of code that I think are relevant.  Store, Customer, and Computer all import java.io.Serializable, all have UIDs, and all implement Serializable.

```
    case 'W':  //Serialize Store to a File
           System.out.print("Please enter the file name to write:\n");
           filename = stdin.readLine().trim();
           FileOutputStream fileOutput = null;
           ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
           try{
               fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(filename);
               outStream = new ObjectOutputStream (fileOutput);
               outStream.writeObject(store1);
               System.out.println("Store written");
               outStream.close();
           }
           catch(NotSerializableException exception){
               System.out.println("NotSerializableException");
           }
           catch(IOException exception){
               System.out.println("IOException");
           }
           finally{
               try{
                   if(outStream != null)outStream.close();
               }
               catch(IOException exe){
                   System.out.println(exe);
               }
           }break;
```

and to deserialize

```
    case 'X':  //Deserialize Store from a File
           System.out.print("Please enter the file name to read:\n");
           filename = stdin.readLine().trim();
           FileInputStream file = null;
           ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
           try{
               file = new FileInputStream(filename);
               inStream = new ObjectInputStream(file);
               Object obj1 = inStream.readObject();
               if(obj1 instanceof Store){
                   store1 = (Store)obj1;
               }
               System.out.println("File was read");
           }
           catch(ClassNotFoundException exception){
               System.out.println("Class was not found");                  
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
               System.out.println(filename +" was not found");
           }
           catch(IOException exception){
               System.out.println("IOException has occurred");
           }
           finally{
               try{
                   if(inStream != null)
                       inStream.close();
               }
               catch(IOException exe){
                   System.out.println(exe);
               }
           }              
           break;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to show us what you do with `store` after you deserialize it. Can we assume these serializable classes have no static or transient members?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code that's posted, which begs the question - what is in the `Store` object you are writing to the file and what happens to `store` after you read it. You can simply cat the file (or type if you are on windows) to see that the file actually contains the objects.

Comment: Here is what I find in the store.dat.  I also tried store.txt to see if it made a difference.  Same characters.  "¬í | sr | StorfA,XO9" then the british pound symbol, a funky U with a line and xp.  Certainly doesn't seem like the type of info for a store...

Comment: Oh no...both array lists are static....

Comment: And that did it.  Of course, now I have to go figure out how to handle methods that were using those variables, but CRAP that should be easier than tracking this down.  I knew to check for transient variables, but I didn't remember to look for statics, too.  Thanks LOTS!!